# How to efficiently find permutations of all coordinates in 2D plane?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to list all coordinates of a 2D plane, with x and y axis ranging from 0 to 1066. Most answers I found recommends creating a list beforehand of all value of x and y axis, but I don't think that is the most efficient, since there will be 1067^2 elements as the result. The list should look something like this:

`list = [(0,0), (0,1),...(0,1066), (1,0), (1,1),...,(1,1066),...,(1066,0),...,(1066,1066)]`.

I was thinking of using permutations since order matters, but I am still figuring out the best method.

Comment: `itertools` is what you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you want if not a list? A generator? Something else?

Comment: I need to use each element later on. So a list is best I guess.

Comment: If you have the coordinates of the plane in some container you can use `itertools` like what Qiu said. A quick guide can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) that you can use to iterate over every single pair of coordinates, without creating a rather large list of values:

As a generator expression:

```
sizex, sizey = 3, 3   # replace with your own values
g = ((x, y) for x in range(sizex) for y in range(sizey))
print(type(g))
for coord in g:
    print(coord)
```

**output:**

```
<class 'generator'>
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

A generator as a lambda function:

```
sizex, sizey = 3, 3   # replace with your own values
g = lambda sizex, sizey: ((x, y) for x in range(sizex) for y in range(sizey))
print(type(g))
for coord in g(sizex, sizey):
    print(coord)
```

#### out:

```
<class 'function'>
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

As a regular function:

```
def g(sizex, sizey):
    for x in range(sizex):
        for y in range(sizey):
            yield(x, y)


sizex, sizey = 3, 3   # replace with your own values
print(type(g))
for coord in g(sizex, sizey):
    print(coord)
```

Comment: is there a way to reuse all of the generated elements? for instance, if I put all result in a list, I can simply iterate the index of element through a function. Can I achieve this without putting them into a list beforehand?

Comment: Yes, you can expand a `generator` into a `list` with `list(generator)`, but why do that when you can iterate over the equivalent `generator`, using very little memory? I added two approaches to create a `generator` with a `lambda`, and with a `regular function` (they are equivalent). In short, you do not need to keep track of the elements to re-use them, you can simply recreate a new generator that will predictably produce the same elements as you iterate over it. The only caveat, is that you need a new generator for each new iteration; when exhausted, a `generator` needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cartesian product to create lazy loading

```
impot itertools
mx, my = 1066, 1066

for x, y in itertools.product(range(mx), range(my)):
    print(x, y)

0 0
0 1
0 2
.
.
.
1065 1063
1065 1064
1065 1065
```